# Which approach is more elegant in express.js api routers?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

I was doing some practice with express and mongoDB, when I was defining API routes I realized that people on the internet does the first method. But I think second is easier to read especially with bigger data. I wonder if there is a difference or a security issue between them. Thanks in advance.

```
    // first approach
    router.route("/add").post((req, res) => {
      const email = req.body.email;
      const password = req.body.password;
      const displayName = req.body.displayName;
      const newUser = new User({ email, password, displayName });
      newUser
        .save()
        .then(() => res.json("OK"))
        .catch((err) => {
          res.status(400).json(err);
        });
    });
    
    // second approach
    router.route("/add").post((req, res) => {
      const newUser = new User({ ...req.body });
      newUser
        .save()
        .then(() => res.json("OK"))
        .catch((err) => {
          res.status(400).json(err);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the perspective of security, they are the same.

In my opinion, the first approach is better, some practical reasons:

- easier for other developers to see the data you are saving
- you may want to do something with the data before saving it
- helps to maintain the consistency of the code (same structure as where the variables are needed)

You can simplify the declarations using the [ES6 destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax.

From:

```
const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;
const displayName = req.body.displayName;
```

To:

```
const { email, password, displayName } = req.body;
```

Also, check the [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript) it may help you decide.

Answer (score 2):

when you use mongoose, based on mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#validateBeforeSave), By default, documents (`req.body`) are automatically validated (based on the schema) before they are saved to the database.

This is to prevent saving an invalid document, so there is not a security issue in second approach and It's easier to read, so can use second approach